# Is there a way to rewrite this raw SQL query with Laravel Query Builder

Tags: laravel

I have two tables:

**products**

```
id | code | supplier_id |...
```

**company_product**

```
id | retail_price | copmany_id |...
```

There are multiple online shops from where I'm pulling the products via their API's which I store locally. It is pretty much used to compare their prices, unit stock, and so on which can be done via product code which is the same across all shops.

I'm fetching all products only once and updating them a couple of times daily. Other companies using this, let's say "platform", have different prices for products based on their contracts which are kept in the second table.

The thing I'm trying to achieve is to list all products but only the cheapest version of the product for that product code.

I am able to achieve it with the following query.

```
$products = DB::select(DB::raw(
    "select p.*, t.price_min
     from (select MAX(p.id) as id, p.code, MIN(cp.retail_price) as price_min
     from products as p
     left join company_product as cp on cp.product_id = p.id
     group by p.code) as t
     left join products as p on p.id = t.id"
));
```

Which gives me the result I want. However, I have lots of filters, sorts, relations, and pagination to add on top of this, which is the reason why I'm trying to rewrite it.

Every suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the raw MySQL query you probably want here is just an inner join:

```
SELECT p.*, t.price_min
FROM products p
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT p.code, MAX(p.id) AS max_id, MIN(cp.retail_price) AS price_min
    FROM products p
    INNER JOIN company_product cp ON cp.product_id = p.id
    GROUP BY p.code
) t
    ON p.id = t.max_id
```

As for the Laravel code, we can try creating the subquery in a separate variable, and then join to it:

```
$subquery = DB::table('products AS p')
    ->select([
        'p.code',
         DB::raw('MAX(p.id) AS max_id, MIN(cp.retail_price) AS price_min')])
    ->join('company_product AS cp', 'cp.product_id', '=', 'p.id')
    ->groupBy('p.code');

$query = DB::table('products AS p')
    ->select('p.*', 't.price_min')
    ->innerJoinSub($subquery, 't', function($join) {
        $join->on('p.id', '=', 't.max_id');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Amazing. This indeed works. Many thanks mate. I changed innerJoinSub to joinSub as it was complaining about undefined method. I was looking into breaking it into multiple queries but wasn't able to syntactically make it work.